# Linq sort date when it's a shortdatestring

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to sort by date with linq when I already have a date brought back from linq that I converted to a shortdatestring:

```
var NOVs = from n in db.CT_NOVs
join i in db.CT_Inspectors on n.ARBInspectorID equals i.CTInspectorID
join v in db.CT_ViolationTypes on n.ViolationTypeID equals v.ViolationTypeID
join t in db.CT_Tanks on n.CargoTankID equals t.CargoTankID
join c in db.CT_Companies on t.CompanyID equals c.CompanyID
select new
{
    n.NOVID,
    n.NOVNumber,
    NOVDate = n.NOVDate.Value.ToShortDateString(),
    ARBInspectorFirstName = i.FirstName,
    ARBInspectorLastName = i.LastName,
    v.ViolationName,
    t.CargoTankID,
    c.CompanyName
};
```

Here is where I try to sort by the date, but it's giving me an error since I converted the datetime into a shortdatestring:

```
if (column == "NOVDate")
{
    if (sortDirection == "ascending")
        NOVs = NOVs.OrderBy(b => Convert.ToDateTime(b.NOVDate));
    else
        NOVs = NOVs.OrderByDescending(b => Convert.ToDateTime(b.NOVDate));
}
```

Any clue on how to sort by NOVDate?

Comment: Looks like you're using an ORM - which one? Might influence outcome...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you leave it as a full DateTime object and convert it to a ShortDateString right before you display it to the user? I usually try to leave the objects in their native format and convert them to display to the user at the last second. That'll help with separating your data layer from your presentation layer too, i.e., let the presentation layer decide how to display the date to the user; your data layer shouldn't really care.

#### From the comments:

Since you're using a `<asp:BoundField>` element with your GridView, you can use the [DataFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) property to have the grid view automatically format it.

It looks like using `DataFormatString="{0:d}"` should do the trick. (thanks [Gromer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104198)!)

Comment: I'm binding the data to a gridview, so it binds automatically

Comment: <asp:BoundField DataField="NOVDate" HeaderText="NOV Date" SortExpression="NOVDate"
                        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />

Comment: Use the [DataFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) property.

Comment: @user1220099, you still are handling all the sorting it looks like, so sort the results before you convert them to the anonymous type.  You'll then be able to sort on the actual DateTime, instead of a string sort.

Comment: And if you leave NOVDate as a date, it would get formatted as per the user's choice. There's no reason to force it to a string before binding.

Comment: @Joshua, man I've been using a lot of `GridView`'s lately, and I totally forgot that.  For sure the best option.

Comment: @user1220099, the syntax for `DataFormatString` on your `DateTime` column in the `GridView` would be `DataFormatString="{0:d}"`

Comment: Thanks Joshua, DataFormatString worked perfect.  Not sure if I used that before.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the "orderby" clause before selecting the elements.

Check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383982.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you sort it first then display it as you want:

```
var NOVs = from n in db.CT_NOVs
               join i in db.CT_Inspectors on n.ARBInspectorID equals i.CTInspectorID
               join v in db.CT_ViolationTypes on n.ViolationTypeID equals v.ViolationTypeID
               join t in db.CT_Tanks on n.CargoTankID equals t.CargoTankID
               join c in db.CT_Companies on t.CompanyID equals c.CompanyID
               orderby n.NOVDate.Value
               select new
               {
                   n.NOVID,
                   n.NOVNumber,
                   NOVDate = n.NOVDate.Value.ToShortDateString(),
                   ARBInspectorFirstName = i.FirstName,
                   ARBInspectorLastName = i.LastName,
                   v.ViolationName,
                   t.CargoTankID,
                   c.CompanyName
               };
```

then you can do this:

```
        if (column == "NOVDate")
        {
            if (sortDirection != "ascending")
                NOVs = NOVs.Reverse();               
        }
```